# Load app package content in Multi-Device Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using the [Multi-Device Hybrid App Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381) (which AFAIK uses cordova) to create a cross-platform app but I can't figure out how to load a content file which is included in the app package.

There doesn't seem to be any Cordova specific API to access app-package content so I tried loading it using a simple jQuery ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./res/resource.txt", // relative path to www folder
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/text",
    success: function (text) {
    },
    error: function (e) {
    }
});
```

but this will result in a **File Not Found** error.
I also tried loading it by using a fully qualified path like so:

```
function getPhoneGapPath() {

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr(0, path.length - 10);
    return 'file://' + path;

};

$.ajax({
    url: getPhoneGapPath()+"/res/resource.txt", // relative path to www folder
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/text",
    success: function (text) {
    },
    error: function (e) {

    }
});
```

but this results in a **Error: Access is denied.** error.
Any hints on how to access the contents of an app package in cordova?

Comment: Are you getting these errors in Ripple, the Android emulator, an Android or iOS device?

Comment: @Dai I tested in Windows 8 (local) and Ripple. haven't managed to get device support to work yet.

Comment: Why not use the FileSystem API?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I can't figure out how. Examples of the FileSystem API all seem to use <input /> to get to a file object.

Comment: Oh? I haven't seen that myself. I've got a few blog posts on the FS API.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths, but lose the `./`

eg

```
$.ajax({
    url: "res/resource.txt", // relative path to www folder
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/text",
    success: function (text) {
    },
    error: function (e) {
    }
});
```

Remember that if you navigate to a deeper path, like /foo/ your relative path will be based off of this.

One solution is to resolve your current path based on the apps absolute path.

On load:

```
var basePath = window.location.href;
```

And then build a relative path based on your current location and the base path.